# NSDateComponentsFormatter format to "mm:ss"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatecomponentsformatter

Im trying to format an *NSTimeInterval* to mm:ss and I want to preserve all the leading zeros, for example "**00:34**"

Im doing the following:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 34.56;
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:interval];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

But this is printing "**0:34**" and I need it to be "**00:34**"

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support for leading zeros for every component with `NSDateComponentsFormatter`.

But you can do such formatting manually:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 34.56;
unsigned int seconds = (unsigned int)interval;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u", (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with manual format is that when the app gets localized it may not be the right format.

Comment: @Hazneliel And forcing leading zeros may not be the right format for a given locale.